# MS SQL Server create user who can access only those databases which they have created

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssms

How to create and give permission to a user in such a way that they will have full access only to the database(s) they have created not other database(s). I am using SQL Server 2016 Express.

Comment: Granting "dbcreator" server role would solve your requirement.

Comment: Can you explain the scenario where or how you  see this being used?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of SQL Server Security!

Probably the best place to start is by reading the [Microsoft Securing SQL Server Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/securing-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). This covers all the basics from securing the physical SQL server to database and user permissions.

An alternative view is the [SQL Server Central Stairway to SQL Server Security](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairways/stairway-to-sql-server-security)

Answer (score 0):

Granting "dbcreator" server role restricts access of the login/user to the databases only created by it, until we don't grant extra permissions.

Thanks!

Comment: I disagree. Ms documentation says: "Members of the dbcreatorfixed server role can create, alter, drop, and restore any database."

Comment: @SirSwears-a-lot Please test & comment back. The same user can create any objects within the database created by him/her. I posted my answer after validation on my environment.

Comment: If a user can drop or restore/overwrite any db IMO that fails to achieve the Ops requirement that they cant access or interfer with other dbs.

Comment: @SirSwears-a-lot That's the question "create and give permission to a user in such a way that they will have full access only to the database(s) they have created not other databases (s)"

Comment: Requirement getting fulfilled this way. Is it necessary to follow MD books online? If the same things fulfill other requirements, what's wrong in that?

Comment: Ok, ill try and test this tommorrow, and will report back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96422/discussion-between-rajesh-ranjan-and-sir-swears-a-lot).

Comment: Hi. So i tested it, and can confirm that a user with DbCreater can interfere with *any* database. I initated a restore action that screwed up a db created by a different user.  Therefore your answer/statement is incorrect, and does not  provide a solution for OP.

Comment: I think you are confusing DB Creater and Db Owner.

Comment: @SirSwears-a-lot User with dbcreator can not interfere with any other database until he is not granted access to the database. I'm not confusing both of the roles. The user becomes default owner of the database who creates it, so he is default db_owner to the database.

Comment: One thing that I agree, "he can backup and restore other databases. But he wouldn't be able to get into it.